# How i can get all files recursively without folders using Get-PnPFolderItem from the root folder and its subfolders

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, administration, pnp-powershell

I want to get all the files from the root folder and its sub-folders, now when I tried this script:

```
$customerFolderFiles = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $serverRelativeUrl -Recursive -ItemType File
```

this will not get the files inside the sub-folders and will only get the files inside the root folder, any fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script will get all the items first, then do the fileter. In your case the cmdlet is like following

```
$customerFolders= $var | Where {$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef -eq $mainfolderUrl -and $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
```

$var is the collection of items. The script get all the items in $var then where clause start filter the data.